# How Do I iterate through all the search results in Selenium returned by google search

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

My test steps are-

- a) go to google.com
- b) in the search box start typing a keyword example "IBM"
- c) google displays all the matching results
- d) Get the count of  matching results in a List of strings.

for (a), (b) I have:-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Work\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
        element.sendKeys("IBM");
```

The Question is how I do (d)?

Answer (score 2):

I have checked the first two results and the locator is same.

So you can create a List of these elements by using FindElements method.

And then put logic to create list of only matching Strings out of it.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you:-

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Work\\chromedriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
driver.manage().window().maximize();
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
element.sendKeys("IBM");
Thread.sleep(1000);
WebElement matchingResult= driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div[@class='aajZCb']/ul"));
List<WebElement> listResult= matchingResult.findElements(By.xpath("//li/div/div[@class='sbtc']"));
System.out.println(listResult.size());
//if you want to print matching results
     for(WebElement results: listResult)
       {
         String value= results.getText();
         System.out.println(value);
       }
```

Comment: Thank you for the code but what I want is a bit different

Comment: when I type IBM before I hit enter I want to get the list of matches. when I type IBM in the search box it comes up with IBM, IBM stock, IBM  Watson, IBM computer and IBM as the possible hints for the keyword. What is the way to capture all those possible hints. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for telling us @CuriousCoder, i have edited the code, hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

While I didn't search for IBM I have done something similar with the a recipe search engine.

```
List<WebElement> searchList = new ArrayList<>(); //creates a list of webelements
    
    //grabbing the search results with a tag
    
    searchList.addAll(driver.findElements(By.tagName("a"))); 
    
    

    
    //Checking size of the arraylist
    
    System.out.println(searchList.size());
```

While as I said that it is not from google I do not know the exact tag you will be looking for this should be a valid answer. Once you have the list of WebElements it should show you the size of the list. If all you want is the umber of items.